# Strange behaviour of comma as decimal separator in handsontable

Tags: javascript, formatting, handsontable

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/stla/Les3vgyd/7/

```
$hot.handsontable({
   data: [{A:"1,2", B:3.1}, {A:2, B:4}] ,
   stretchH: "none",
   manualColumnResize: [100,100],
   colHeaders: ["A","B"],
   comments: true,
   columnSorting: true,
   undo: true,
   columns: [
    {data: "A", type: "numeric", format: "0.[00000000000000]", language: 'en-US'},
    {data: "B", type: "numeric", format: "0.[00000000000000]"}
   ]
});
```

The situation is the following one. The user of an app uploads some data (say from an Excel file for example) and the table is rendered in the app with `handsontable`.

The data are supposed to be numeric only. But there's an error in the Excel file: the guy who filled the sheet typed `1,2` instead of `1.2`, and `1,2` has a text format.

Then, as expected, the table is rendered like this:
[image]

Now, when I only double-click on the cell `1,2`, as if I wanted to edit it, but I don't edit anything and only press enter, then the character string `1,2` becomes the number `12`:
[image]

Similarly, when I edit the cell containing the number `4`, and type `4,32`, then the content of this cell becomes the number `432`:

[image]

This is an unexpected behaviour for me. For example when I edit a cell and enter a character, this character is rendered as-is and the cell becomes red:

[image]

This behaviour is the one I expect.

Is there an option to set, in order that when I enter e.g. `4,32` in a cell, then this input is taken as a character string, and is rendered as-is with a red background, like the above example when I enter `a` ? And not as the number `432`.

Comment: My guess is they clean up commas for thousand separators and do not check if it is a valid number before.

Comment: In addition to epascarello comment, they clean up everything in your input. try to put 4a32, you will still get 432.

Comment: Yes. This is generated by `numbro` in `Handsontable.NumericRenderer`. For example `numbro("1a,3").format("0.0")` gives `"13.0"`. And `numbro("a").format("0.0")` gives `"NaN"`. So I would like `"1a,3"` => `"NaN"`.